# What length of chat history is visible for new entrants in a Private Telegram Group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-group

Can you please provide information about how many previous messages a new entrant into a Private Telegram Group can see?

I tried to look at the settings, on Telegram Desktop, under "Manage group", but I don't see it there.

[image: Telegram Private Group settings]

Answer (score 1):

Chat history for new members can be 1. Visible or 2. Hidden

When *visible* new members will see messages sent before they joined.

When *hidden* new members won't see more than 100 previous messages.

Locate this feature by clicking on edit button in your group info page.